# No Product matches the given query. Django

Tags: python, django

I created `BlogPost` class. Then created ListView `BlogPostListView` and `blogpost_detail`.

**ADDED diff off all change that affected error** -- https://pastebin.com/DyukCYq9

When I clicked to post name (on this page https://edamer.ru/blog_posts/)

I was redirected to the valid url. But I received error instead product_detail page:

> Page not found. http://127.0.0.1:8001/blog_post/1/

> Raised by:    blog.views.product_detail. No Product matches the given query.

I can't understand why `product_detail()` called instead of `blogpost_detail()`
Also error text said about **Product** (**Product** - is name of another model in my app. But I was calling `BlogPost` (not Product)

**I tried**

1. python manage.py flush # clear database
2. Review my changes. But did not find calls of  `product_detail()`

**I think that error deals with invalid urls**

**My code**

**views.py**

```
def product_detail(request, **kwargs):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=kwargs["pk"])
    shops = Shop.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'blog/product_detail.html', {'product': product, 'shops': shops})


class BlogPostListView(ListView):
    model = BlogPost
    template_name = 'blog/post_list.html'
    page_kwarg = 'blog_post'
    context_object_name = 'blog_posts'


def blogpost_detail(request, **kwargs):
    post = get_object_or_404(BlogPost, pk=kwargs["pk"])
    return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', {'post': post})
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', HomePageView.as_view(), name='main_list'),
    path('search/', SearchResultsView.as_view(), name='search_results'),
    path('search_shop/<slug:slug>/', ProductListView.as_view(), name='search_shop'),
    path('search_shop_results/<slug:slug>/', ProductSearchResultsView.as_view(), name='search_shop_results'),
    path('<slug:slug>/<int:pk>/', views.product_detail, name='product_detail'),

    path('shops/', ShopListView.as_view(), name='shop_list'),
    path('contacts/', views.contacts, name='contacts'),

    path("robots.txt", TemplateView.as_view(template_name="blog/robots.txt", content_type="text/plain")),
    url(r'^sitemap\.xml$', sitemap, {'sitemaps': sitemaps}, name='django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap'),
    url(r'^favicon\.ico$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/static/favicon.ico'), name='favicon'),

    path('register/', views.RegisterFormView.as_view(), name="register"),
    path('login/', views.LoginFormView.as_view(), name="login"),
    path('logout/', views.LogoutView.as_view(), name="logout"),

    path('blog_posts/', views.BlogPostListView.as_view(), name='post_list'),
    path('blog_post/<int:pk>/', blogpost_detail, name='blogpost_detail'),
]
```

**post_list.html**

```
{% for post in blog_posts %}
        <a href="{% url 'blogpost_detail' post.pk %}" style="text-decoration: none;color:inherit;">
            {{post.title}}
        </a>
        <p>{{post.prev_text}}</p>
        <br>
{% endfor %}
```

**post_detail.html**

```
<h1>Post detail</h1>

<div class="container" style="margin-top: 40px; font-size: 1.2rem; padding-left: 0px;">
    <h1>{{post}}</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess you have imported your view this way

```
from . import views
```

So you need to get it this way

```
path('blog_post/<int:pk>/', views.blogpost_detail, name='blogpost_detail'),
```

Comment: I added ```path('blog_post/<int:pk>/', views.blogpost_detail, name='blogpost_detail')```. But error remains

Comment: can you upload you product_detail view as the error persist there and i think in your post template {post.pk} should be {post.id}

Comment: added product_detail() to views,py

Comment: In your post detail template where are you getting the post context from as you have only mention product and shops as the context

Comment: And how can I fix it?

Comment: change this {{post}} to this {{product}} in your post_detail.html